# Protractor IE 11 Error - Failed to find element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

Using the following syntax to find a username input text box,

```
browser.findElement(By.id('username'));
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but has the following error in IE 11:

```
    [internet explorer #3]   Message:
    [internet explorer #3]     Failed: Finding elements with id ==usernamereturned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    [internet explorer #3]     Command duration or timeout: 970 milliseconds
    [internet explorer #3]     For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    [internet explorer #3]     Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
    [internet explorer #3]     System info: host: 'dev-web-01', ip: '10.126.1.32', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
    [internet explorer #3]     Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    [internet explorer #3]     Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false
    expectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    [internet explorer #3]     Session ID: d593cfc5-74a5-445a-b1b8-fcdf7c372786
    [internet explorer #3]     *** Element info: {Using=id, value=username}
```

I've followed the following two sites to configure IE:
[seleniumQuery](https://github.com/seleniumQuery/seleniumQuery)
[Run Protractor Against Internet Explorer VM](http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/)

Answer (score 2):

I understand this post was 2 yrs ago but want to post this so that its useful for people with similar issues. I work in a cloud server with 2012 window server, IE11, 3.12 IEdriver, 5.3 protractor, 8.0.1 promise, .9.5 cucumber.

The script was opening IE but couldn't identify any objects until I reached following changes.

1. IE11 cannot be used with direct connect. port 4444 doesn't work for me.
2. Change following Settings: 
   2.1 Enable Protected Mode - On or Off in all zones for IE11
   2.2 Zone -> Internet-> Custom -> Scripting -> Active Scripting -> Enable
3. Config file with Cucumber Framework

   ```
   exports.config = {
       getPageTimeout: 60 * 1000,
       allScriptsTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
       restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,

       capabilities: {
           browserName:'internet explorer',
           version: 'ANY',

           restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
           shardTestFiles: false,
           maxInstances: 1,
           enableElementCacheCleanup: true,
           javascriptEnabled: true,
           ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true
       },
       framework: 'custom',
       frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
       ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,

       specs: [
           '../SystemStatus/*.feature'
       ],
       cucumberOpts: {
           require: ['../SystemStatus/SystemStatus.steps.js'],
           format: 'json:../../report/SystemStatus'+ timeStamp + '/report.json',
           //format: ['pretty'],
           //tags: [],
           strict: true,
           dryRun: false,
           compiler: [],
           tags: '@Login'

       },


       plugins: [{
           package: require.resolve('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'),
           options:{
               automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
               removeExistingJsonReportFile: true
           }
       }]

   };
   ```